# What ghc package does cabal-install need?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, software-installation, haskell

I've just installed cabal to try and get http://dmwit.com/yeganesh/, but on running cabal-install it throws the error:

> cabal: ghc version >=6.4 is required but it could not be found.

Apt-cache searching ghc returns literally hundreds of packages, which one do I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the one called exactly `ghc`.

- Ubuntu: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ghc
- Debian: http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/ghc

You can add the `--names-only` option to `apt-cache search` to limit your results; it prevents it from returning a positive result for packages that only mention ghc in the description. If that fails, I go to the package search page on the distro website where I can search for filenames instead of package names.

Comment: You can search for file names locally as well: `apt-cache search bin/ghc`